# OnTouchListener on parent view is not getting called when there is a click listener for child views

Tags: android, android-layout, ontouchlistener

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/actions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/action_previous"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/action_next"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/action_previous"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="7"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ImageActivity.kt

```
swipe_parent.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
  Toast.makeText(this@ImageActivity, "OnTouch called $v, $event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  return@setOnTouchListener true
}

action_previous.setOnClickListener {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Previous", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

action_next.setOnClickListener {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

I read in many comments stating if there is a onClickListener for child view then OnTouchListener call won't be passed to the parent (If the views are structured as above) . And logically it makes sense as well, as it would be hard to differentiate between the clicks and touch.

If this is my requirement, how do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to resolve this problem would be using ontouch instead of onclick,
but mimic the onclick functionality, inside the child view ontouch check this condition, it is only executed for action_down case only which would be helpful in your case.

```
if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I resolved it by setting

```
android:clickable="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in the parent view.

Comment: Will you please elaborate on what according to your app requirement is touch and what is a click?